Lower Bound for Evaluating an Interpolation Polynomial at a Single Point Without Preprocessing
I am investigating the complexity of evaluating an interpolation polynomial at a given point $x$ without any preprocessing. Here’s the situation:
Suppose I have $n$ points $M = \{(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ... ,(x_n, y_n)\} \subset \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and a point $x\in\mathbb{R}$. The goal is to compute the value of the interpolation polynomial $P_M(x)$. The interpolation polynomial can be expressed in either Lagrange or Newton form, but both involve multiplications if no preprocessing is allowed.
I know that it is possible to evaluate the polynomial $P_M$ at $n$ points at an average number of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ multiplications. This could be achieved by calculating $P_M$ using Newton's method in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ and evaluating at $n$ points using Horner's method in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ for each polynomial, to get a total average runtime of $\frac{\mathcal{O}(n^2) + n \cdot\mathcal{O}(n)}{n} = \mathcal{O}(n)$.
This is not what I am interested in though. I am wondering weather it is possible to evaluate $P_M$ at only one point faster than $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$.
It is at least obvious, that a lower bound of the computational complexity is $\in \mathcal{O}(n)$, since $P_M$ depends on all $n$ points.
My conjecture is that the lower bound on the number of multiplications is indeed $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$, but I was not able to prove it yet. Is this conjecture correct? What could be another lower bound on the complexity if a faster algorithm is known?

So basically you are asking the flops of solving Vandermonde matrix. I believe It is possible to get faster evaluation, like $O(n\log n)$. You should be able to find some references by searching Vandermonde matrix and FFT together. One example to think about is the Chebyshev interpolation, which exactly is computing FFT.
